# Firebase on value change is not updating the UI

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

i try to get some Data from my Firebase Database with the following Code in my EventDetails Page

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.eventData.viewEventService(this.eventID).then(snapshot =>{
      console.log("Update on Loading")
      this.updateUI(snapshot);
    });
  }
```

EventData provider

```
viewEventService(eventID:any): Promise<any>{
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            this.eventsNode.child(eventID)
                .on('value', data => {
                console.log("Changes");
                resolve(data);
            });
        });
    }
```

When i enter the Detailspage everthing works fine and if i change some stuff in my Database the console output "Changes" is also successful.
The Problem is that my Views in the Detailpage are not updated till i refresh the window.

Also the console.log("Update in loading") is not triggered so my updateUI function is not called.

Can somebody help me to solve this issue?
Do i have to call the function somewhere else then in ionViewDidload() cause its only triggered when the view is loading?

Comment: I guess you have a problem with scoping of this at line 4: this.updateUI(snapshot);

Comment: but if the scoping of this is the reason why there is also no output at console.log? What do you think i should change?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle of the problem above? there definitely seems to be no issue with firebase connection.

Comment: Sorry, i'm relatively new to coding in ionic2, dont know how i could set up the problem in jsfiddle